# Scala - iterate through specific type

Tags: scala, avro

I am working with Scala and Avro and in one moment - variable type is:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def getType[T: TypeTag](value: T) = typeOf[T]
println(getType(schema))

// Output:
org.apache.avro.Schema
```

and values in it:

```
println("schema:" + schema)
schema:["null","string"]
```

How to iterate trough it? (and check if at least one field is defined as 'null' -> in this case first one is null).

Tried:

```
for(k <- schema) {
        println("k: " + k)
      }

// value foreach is not a member of org.apache.avro.Schema
```

Comment: have you tried some searching ? Perhaps this links will help you : https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.5.4/api/java/org/apache/avro/Schema.html

Comment: @volia Thanks.. I can see API docs but still need a help of example (how to use some of the methods to iterate..). I am still new-ish to Scala / Spark / Avro, that's why asking here.. Do you mind sharing implementation example of it? (then I can test and approve your full answer). Thanks again..